# get current->pid while in interrupt

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduling, interrupt-handling

I'm writing something on the linux scheduler and I need to know which process was running before my interrupt came in.. is the current structure available? If I do current->pid while in the interrupt handler, do I get the pid of the process I interrupted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, `current->pid` exists and is the process that was interrupted (may be the idle thread, or any).

If you're writing inside the Linux scheduler, you should be very careful. `current` is changed by the scheduler as it chooses a new process to run, so its value depends on when exactly you read it.

Comment: *current* just masks low bits of %esp, right? And there is something called interrupt stack in Linux. If the interrupt switched you to other stack and you mask %esp, then you're nowhere near any valid struct task_info. IOW task_info is part of stack, you won't find it on interrupt stack. I'm I missing something?

Comment: @mooray, `current` works. `current` first gets the `thread_info` (in x86, by masking %esp), where it finds a pointer to `task_struct`. When switching to an interrupt stack, `do_IRQ` sets this pointer according to the process's kernel stack.

Comment: @ugoren, sorry for waking this old thread but could you clarify one more point? As far as I can see in the kernel sources, `current` must indeed work on 32-bit x86 systems as you described, `execute_on_irq_stack()` stores the correct pointer to `task_struct` in the thread info for the IRQ. But what about x86-64? It seems, there is no thread info in or near `irq_stack_union` there, and I haven't found the code yet that sets `task` field appropriately on this architecture. Perhaps, I am missing something?

Comment: @Eugene, I'm not sure about the mechanism, but it's handled. When a process is interrupted, `current` points to the process. Indeed x86_64 makes things more complicated due to stack replacement, but it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect *current* to be valid outside process context. If you're working on scheduler maybe you can get hold of where it stores pointer to running task, e.g. struct cfs_rq.